# How to Detect Road in NavAR using BeyondAR and draw a line using GeoObjects

Tags: android, navigation, augmented-reality

I am using sample code from [ArNAV](https://github.com/KrishAmal/NavAR) in my android app and so far I modified a lot of code to use in my AR app. I am stuck on one issue. My requirement is to place Geo Objects on road by detecting the road. Is there any way to do that using [BeyondAR](https://github.com/BeyondAR/beyondar) framework?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution to above problem?
I too wants to do this.

Comment: @RonakBadjatya No, I did not.